# Flask helper classes and return values

Tags: python, oop, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-login

**Greetings,**

I am working with Flask and trying to create some helper classes instead of doing the data logic in the "controllers"/"routes", but my problem is that it doesn't seem to return anything at all, therefore I am struggling to actually get any data out from it.

The relevant folder structure I am using looks like this:

```
[app]
├── main_blueprint
│    ├── __init__.py
│    ├── controller.py
│    └── forms.py
├── classes
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── auth.py
├── __init__.py
├── models.py
└── ...
```

well in my `main_blueprint.__init__.py` I simply just made a blueprint and named it main

and in models I am using flask-sqlalchemy as ORM model. Where I use module plugins such as

- flask-login
- werkzeug.security

## auth.py

Here I am trying to create a helper class for authentication, which will do the selected work for the specific task. 
So far it looks like:

```
from ..models import User
from flask.ext.login import login_required, login_user, logout_user
from flask import render_template, redirect, url_for, request

class Auth():
    def login(self, email, password, remember_me):
        user = User.query.filter_by(user_email=email).first()
        if user is None or not user.verify_password(password):
            return redirect(url_for('main.none'))
        login_user(user, remember_me)
        return redirect(url_for('main.yes'))
```

But my problem is that I try to initialize the object with a method, it is not directing to anything at all, I even tried creating a little method for class Auth()

```
def test(self):
       return redirect(url_for('main.index'))
```

and see if it will redirect at all, but no luck.

## controller.py

And here it is in the controller.class

```
from flask import render_template, redirect, url_for, request
from .forms import LoginForm
from flask.ext.login import login_required, login_user, logout_user
from ..classes.auth import Auth

@main.route('/none')
def none():
    test = 'not working'
    return render_template('index.html', test=test)

@main.route('/yes')
@login_required
def yes():
    test = 'yes working'
    return render_template('index.html', test=test)
```

and my route for login:

```
@main.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    form = LoginForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        a = Auth()
        a.login(form.username.data, form.password.data, form.remember_me.data)
    return render_template('login.html', form=form)
```

but the thing is if I didn't create it as a helper class it is working,

```
 @main.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
 def login():
     form = LoginForm()
     if form.validate_on_submit():
        return redirect(url_for('main.index'))
        # TODO Craete all this in a class
        user = User.query.filter_by(user_email=form.username.data).first()
        if user is None or not user.verify_password(form.password.data):
            return (url_for('main.none', **request.args))
        login_user(user, form.remember_me.data)            
        return redirect(request.args.get('next') or url_for('main.yes'))
        # End Class
     return render_template('login.html', form=form)
```

## User model

```
in case you need to see the User model:
from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash, check_password_hash
from flask.ext.login import UserMixin

class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_email = db.Column(db.String(128), unique=True)
    user_password = db.Column(db.String(128))

    @property
    def password(self):
        raise AttributeError('password is not a readable attribute')

    @password.setter
    def password(self, password):
        self.user_password = generate_password_hash(password)

    def verify_password(self, password):
        return check_password_hash(self.user_password, password)

# TODO create this in user class DAO
@lm.user_loader
def load_user(id):
    return User.query.get(int(id))
# END
```

lm is a loginmanager object.

So my question is simply, how should I convert the logic to a class? (some kind of abstract layer class). And before you ask, why not make it script(function) instead of a class, is because I will create helper classes later which will be needed as a object, so why not learn OOP way? ;)

**Thanks in advance**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot a `return`.

```
@main.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    form = LoginForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        a = Auth()
        # without this return it will fall through to render_template
        return a.login(form.username.data, form.password.data, form.remember_me.data)
    return render_template('login.html', form=form)
```

Comment: Auch, thanks a lot dirn! It struggled me for hours and didn't think of just adding return! I thought it was enough to add it to the methods! Cheers!